# ASP config environment variables in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using `docker-compose` for my `ASP.NET Core 2.0` services. Services configurations are done mostly in `appsettings.Test.json`, but some values should be overridden through environment variables, because I want to be able to reuse one docker image over multiply environments.
For example, I have the next settings in the `appsettings.Test.json`

```
"CorsPolicy": {
    "Origins": [
        "old:1",
        "old:2"
    ]
},
```

And I want to override them with another array of origins in my `docker-compose` file:

```
some-service:
    image: some-image:tag1
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: 'Test'
      CorsPolicy__Origins__0: 'https://NEW:1'
      CorsPolicy__Origins__1: 'ttps://NEW:2'
```

But my values from `appsettings.Test.json` weren't overridden. The problem is only with array values. If I try any flat structure, it works just fine.

**Update:**
Important detail-if I add the same array of origins to `launchSettings.json` in `VisualStudio` it works (all values from `appsettings.Test.json` were overriden). So the problem is only in `docker-compose` file.

Comment: I'm not entirely confident in how `asp.net-core` does things. But the way we do things at my office is the other way around; you overwrite the service configuration file with environment variables set by your `docker-compose`, which in turn gets its variables overwritten by env variables.

Comment: That being said, you will have to look at how you overwrite the `appsettings.json` file from environment variables to make that work. 

We have exclusively `.yaml` files, which are a subset of `.json`, which uses the `$` prefix to get values from environment variables. This is then cascaded down from an env-file to `docker-compose` and down to our services.